# How do I run a "regular" W&B session after I've done a sweep?

Tags: wandb

I have the following code

```py
def train(config=None, run_num=None, project=None):
    with wandb.init(project=project, config=config) as run:
        config = wandb.config
        # Working training code...

sweep_id = wandb.sweep(sweep_config, project="ABC")
wandb.agent(sweep_id, train, count=2)

for run_num in range(2):
    train(config={'batch_size': 32, 'learning_rate': 0.001, 'fc_layer_size': 2, 'dropout': 0}, project="XYZ")
```

The training works as expected, but I can only do *either* the loop or a sweep. If I do a sweep followed by a loop, the provided config is ignored and the config used by the preceding sweep is used instead.

When the config setting is attempted in the looping version, I also get the error

> Changes to your `wandb` environment variables will be ignored because your `wandb` session has already started. For more information on how to modify your settings with `wandb.init()` arguments, please refer to the [W&B docs](https://docs.wandb.ai/ref/python/init).

Referring to the documents makes it seem like what I'm doing should be working.

How do I run a "regular" W&B session after I've done a sweep?

Comment: FWIW, for fun I tried this in ChatGPT (GPT-4) and it just invented arguments for `wandb.agent`: first `block` (set to true) and then `done_callback` (set to the training loop).